# Matrox Millenium g400, WinXP - How to enable 1680x1050?

Tags: windows-xp, graphics-card, resolution

It's an old computer like 2001 or so, Matrox Millenium g400. How to enable 1680x1050?

Drivers updated from 2006, tried to use Powerstrip, still nothing, got some res to choose but not the needed one.

Is it possible at all? Or should I find some replacement video card or what?

**Edit:**

In Powerstrip the 'advanced timing options' button is grayed out and can't get it to work.

[image]

"hide modes not supported by this monitor" is of course unchecked.

Comment: Apparently the disabled button can be caused by "Hide modes not supported by this monitor" being checked in Display properties as well

Comment: that is an *OLD* card...  I had one of those back in the day.  It was nice for 10 years ago :)

Comment: @Keltari, feel free to buy them a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Set up a custom resolution in Powerstrip, I believe the card is capable of it but it does not expose resolutions it is capable of outside of 4:3 aspect ratio resolutions.

Comment: +1 PowerStrip IS able to 'trick' the g400 into 1680x1050.

Comment: the thing is, the 'advanced timing options' button is grayed out and can't get it to work. http://i.imgur.com/5EjrKl.png . "hide modes not supported by this monitor" is of course unchecked.

Comment: Apparently that can be caused by "Hide modes not supported by this monitor" being checked in Display properties as well.

Comment: look at what i wrote above and the screenshot

Comment: That's Powerstrip, not Display properties. http://safecomputing.open.ac.uk/health2.gif

Comment: yeah, and i told that 'hide modes' is UNchecked. nvm, what else can block the advanced timing? i'm stuck.